# Create empty table with rows and column names in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rows, names, matlab-table

I'm new to Matlab so I'm stuck on a problem where I need to create table with certain rows and columns names.

```
CameraCar = array2table(zeros(0,20), 'VariableNames',{"c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9","c10","c11","c12","c13","c14","c15","c16","c17","c18","c19","c20"},'RowNames',{1:800});
```

I've tried using above line on code but I get error(mentioned below) in creating it.

> Error using
>   matlab.internal.tabular.private.rowNamesDim/validateAndAssignLabels
>   (line 109) The RowNames property must be a cell array, with each
>   element containing one nonempty character vector.
>
> Error in matlab.internal.tabular.private.tabularDimension/setLabels
>   (line 173)
>               obj = obj.validateAndAssignLabels(newLabels,indices,fullAssignment,fixDups,fixEmpties,fixIllegal);
>
> Error in
>   matlab.internal.tabular.private.tabularDimension/createLike_impl (line
>   355)
>                   obj = obj.setLabels(dimLabels,[]);
>
> Error in matlab.internal.tabular.private.tabularDimension/createLike
>   (line 62)
>                   obj = obj.createLike_impl(dimLength,dimLabels);
>
> Error in tabular/initInternals (line 206)
>               t.rowDim = t.rowDim.createLike(nrows,rowLabels);
>
> Error in table.init (line 327)
>               t = initInternals(t, vars, numRows, rowLabels, numVars, varnames);
>
> Error in array2table (line 64)
>       t = table.init(vars,nrows,rownames,nvars,varnames);
>
> Error in CarMatrix (line 1) CameraCar = array2table(zeros(0,20),
>   'VariableNames',{"c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9","c10","c11","c12","c13","c14","c15","c16","c17","c18","c19","c20"},'RowNames',{1:800});

Comment: There are many mistakes but why do you want to create an empty table?

Comment: I need to fill the table according to the available data, programatically

Comment: Then why you need it *empty*? You can fill it with zeros or any other values and then just replace the values

Comment: The trick is to use `cell2table` or `array2table`, if you use `array2table` then you have to use an array of `zeros` or `nan` to fill the elements. A cell array can be an array of empty elements. If you want to specify row names then the cell or array has to have the correct number of rows.

Comment: Whilst it is possible to fill it with empty cells, it will be better to fill it with zeros or NaNs or any other values instead. Otherwise, later on you would need to convert your matrices to cell again to store elements at those places which overall seems to be an over-kill in my opinion

Comment: I need empty or zero valued cells to keep the count of data available. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
% Get your row numbers (optional as the table already gives these numbers
% as default)
rowNumbers = 1:1:800;
% Convert to cellarray
myCellArray = num2cell(rowNumbers);
% Convert numbers to strings
myCellArray = cellfun(@num2str, myCellArray, 'UniformOutput', false);
% Set up table
CameraCar = array2table(zeros(800,20), 'VariableNames',{'c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7',...
    'c8','c9','c10','c11','c12','c13','c14','c15','c16','c17','c18','c19','c20'},'RowNames',myCellArray);
```